# Redirect not stopping re-submission?

Tags: php, post-redirect-get

## PHP

```
    $thisfile=$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    
    if(isset($_POST['comment'])&&!empty($_POST['comment'])){
    if($id!=0){
    $comment=$_POST['comment'];
    
    if ($comment_query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `photosite`.`comments` VALUES ('$id', '', '$firstname', '$surname', '$photo_id', '$comment', '$time')")){
    
    header('Location: photopage.php?photo_id='.$photo_id.'', true, 303);
    exit;
    
    }else {
    echo 'Could not add comment';
    }
    }else {
    echo'Please Log In to add a Comment';
    }
    }
```

I do not get why my

```
header('Location: photopage.php?photo_id='.$photo_id.'', true, 303);
    exit;
```

Still alowas the user to resubmit data? This links to the same page because it is for adding comments so when a user adds a comment, the page refreshes to the same page. But if you refresh again, the content is re-submitted, any idea why?

UPDATE:
I **DO** have stuff echoed out before all this code in the same document. Is that the problem?

Ok I changed the form action to another page to be processed. There were previous things outputting to the page which was the problem!

Comment: first of all: Make sure to escape your data: `$comment=$_POST['comment'];` => `$comment=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comment']);`, or much better: use prepared statements. Second: 303 is an excellent choice, and made for this situation. Your code looks valid (as: it should work). What is your definition of "resubmit data"?

Comment: @John  303 because it clears the cache. Ok so I submit a comment and the page refreshes and I can see the comment I post. Then if I refresh it asks about Confirm Form Re-Submission? I click continue and the comment is re-added.

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL); please add this to Your code, then submit the form, I think You'll receive warning "Cannot modify headers, headers already sent ... '

Comment: header("Location: .. "); might not work without ob_start(); http://stackoverflow.com/a/15235909/1880351 @user2127833

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
...
header('Location: /photopage.php?photo_id='.$photo_id.'', true, 303);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 header('Location: photopage.php?photo_id='.$photo_id.'&added='.time());
    exit;
```

should work. The code you provided should also work. The header->location removes the POST contents, so if you refresh the page afterwards, it should not resubmit.

Pressing the BACK button is a different story, you cannot solve that, unless you are using an unique token for every form request.

Example:

```
 //check if the token in the session matches the token in the post
 if( isset( $_POST['token'], $_SESSION['token']) 
     && $_SESSION['token'] == $_POST['token'] ){
    //handle your post data
     [...]
 }

 //set the token
 $_SESSION['token'] = sha1(time().mt_rand());

 //process your form
 ?>
 [...]
 <input type='hidden' name='token' value='<?php echo $_SESSION["token"];?>'/>
 [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, seems I have find out your problem.. I think Your error reporting is switched off, so You don't see the warning about headers, "Cannot modify header information – headers already sent ...".
You cant send header or modify them, as there are sent, because of that You must turn on buffering. Use `ob_start()` on the top of Your code. It must look like this

```
<?php
ob_start();
..
```

Don't use any whitespaces before `<?php`.

And remove the parameter true, 303 from Your header function..

```
header('Location: photopage.php?photo_id='.$photo_id);
exit();
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

Comment: I usually get that error code on other pages, which is when I use this. But I added it and it didnt work... Maybe something with this line in my form? `<form action="<?php $current_file;?>" method="POST">` current file...  `$current_file = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];`

Comment: If Your form submits on same page, You can write action=""

Comment: the ob_start() must be the first called function, if Your script includes from somewhere (e.g. index.php) You must write ob_start on the top of index.php.

Comment: Ok well I removed it and it works as normal but the form re submission is still happening. This is very weird. Well I guess I will just have to ignore it for now...

Comment: I have `ob_start();` under the first <?php tag I have in the document.

Comment: But like I said above your comment, I had put `ob_start();` directly under my first <?php tag.

Comment: I'm not about comments. I updated my answer. Remove the parameters true and 303, and it will work.

Comment: I actually tried that before I posted the question, I re-tried and it didn't work.

Comment: I am thinking it is not reading `header('Location: photopage.php?photo_id='.$photo_id.'', true, 303);
    exit;` right. Or I didn't use it right.

Comment: the statement is correct, I cannot understand why it not working.. but when I added params true, 303 to my existing code, my script started to work such yours, redirection when I hit F5 browsers asks about resumbission, because of that, I thought the problem was there..

Comment: Oh I **DO** have stuff echoed out before all this code in the same document.